# MS Teams Channel email address does not work

Tags: microsoft-teams

Emails sent to the address from the MS-Teams Channel's `...` menu's `Get email address` are returned with the error message "Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups: Could not create the email message on Microsoft Teams: the channel's folder was deleted or renamed.  The channel has not been deleted or renamed, as I just got the email address from the channel's `...` menu.

How do I fix this?

returned email (ids, servernames, and hashcodes replaced):

> Delivery has failed to these recipients or groups:
>
> channelid.corpname.com@amer.teams.ms Could not create the email
>   message on Microsoft Teams: the channel's folder was deleted or
>   renamed.
>
> Diagnosticinformation for administrators:
>   messageId:<(hashcode1).(servername).outlook.com>, serverRequestId:
>   hashcode2, clientRequestId: hashcode3

Comment: Was the SharePoint folder for the channel ever renamed? That might cause this. Can you delete (remove) it and create a new email address?

Comment: SharePoint folder was not renamed.  Deleted (removed) and created new email address: problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft informed us that it is an Office 365 issue.  Nothing for us to do.  Microsoft has to fix it on their end.